# Can homology record the existence of a hole built from nonnegative combinations of simplicies?

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Let $A$ be an abstract simplicial complex, and let $\partial$ be the top-level boundary operator.  Suppose we want to know whether $\ker(\partial)$ contains any terms (besides 0 itself) built by *nonnegative* linear combinations (i.e. coefficients in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$) of the top-level simplices. Is this information reflected in any way in the homology groups of $A$?  If not, are there any alternate homology-like theories that can make this sort of distinction?

Comment: Is this really a question on homological algebra? I think you are asking if the zero eigenspace of a matrix intersects the non-negative cone outside zero.